# How do the verbs do and δίδωμι come from *deh₃-?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, greek, proto-indo-european

I was a little surprised to find that the PIE root of do and δίδωμι is *deh₃-, not *do-. How did we get the "o" vowel sound from eh₃? I don't actually know how to pronounce h₃, but I'm assuming that *deh₃- rhymes with "meh"... correct me if I am wrong here.

This question popped up when I was looking up "anecdote" in a dictionary and reading its etymology. I saw that the word derives from ἐκ + δίδωμι (to give out, publish). The familiar root "do" is present. But when I looked up the origins of "do", I found *deh₃-.

(There you have it: an anecdote about *anecdote*.)

I might as well include a guess. My guess is this. *deh₃- became *di-deh₃-, but *di-do was considered a euphonic improvement somewhere down the line, hence δίδωμι. And, as Wiktionary suggests, the reduplication was lost in Latin, giving *do*.

Comment: If you make your anecdotes any more meta, they have to be taken to [the meta site](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/). Seriously, though, the question is interesting! But you should not be fooled by the first person singular ending *-o*; the Latin stem seems to be *da-*.

Comment: `meh₃` does not necessarily rhyme with `meh`, in fact, nobody knows (so it might actually rhyme anyways !). `h₃` is basically a hypothetical unknown phoneme that influences vowel quality in PIE. It explains a lot of exceptions to sound change laws from the reconstructed PIE language to the attested ancient IE languages. If you've got time to kill, you can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laryngeal_theory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

δίδωμι “I give” and δίδομεν “we give” can be explained either by “classic” (non-laryngeal) or “modern” (laryngeal) theory. The former derives the singular from full-grade *dō- and the plural from zero-grade *də- (with secondary ə>o by analogy). The latter posits full-grade *deh<sub>3</sub>- > dō- and zero-grade *dh<sub>3</sub>- > do; δίδωμι is then from *di-deh<sub>3</sub>-mi, and δίδομεν from *di-dh<sub>3</sub>-men.

By the way, you are not alone in not knowing how to pronounce h<sub>3</sub>. Nobody knows how it was pronounced. It is a quasi-algebraic symbol.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. So the full grade of *deh3 is dō. It sounds like PIE roots often underwent full-grade vowel changes? Was there a tendency for vowels to either become full-grade or zero-grade?

Comment: @ktm5124, vowel grade variation (aka ablaut) was an integral part of PIE grammar, so there's no general answer to your question -- the grade depends on the specific grammatical form (and isn't always predictable even then). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_ablaut

Answer (score 12):

**h<sub>3</sub>* is called the "o-colouring laryngeal," which means that it "colours" (i.e., changes) a neighbouring *e* into **o* or **ō*: the former from **h<sub>3</sub>o* and the latter from **oh<sub>3</sub>*. See **h<sub>3</sub>ewis* > *ovis* and **deh<sub>3</sub>[r/n]m̥* > *dōnum*.

Now, when **h<sub>x</sub>* (or any other laryngeal) is **not** next to an **e*, then they yield other vowels: **a* in Latin, **i* in Sanskrit, and **e*, **a* or **o* in Greek respectively for **h<sub>1</sub>*, **h<sub>2</sub>* and **h<sub>3</sub>*.

[Rasmussen](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=--ssbDUSJfIC&redir_esc=y) postulates **h<sub>1</sub>* to be the voiceless glottal fricative [h] (though some postulate it as the glottal stop [ʔ]) when acting as a consonant, and the unrounded central vowel [ə] when acting as the nucleus of a syllable; **h<sub>2</sub>* to be the voiceless velar fricative [x] (others postulating the pharyngeal approximant [ʕ] in a consonant role and the near open central vowel [ɐ] in a syllable nucleus; and finally **h<sub>3</sub>* to be the labialised velar fricative [ɣʷ] (though [xʷ] and [ʕʷ] also have adherents) in consonant mode and the rounded central vowel [ɵ] in a syllable nucleus.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Interesting to learn how the laryngeals affect their neighbors. I don't think I have seen you here before, so allow me to say, welcome to the site!