# Why is it "dare" and not "dāre" when most first conjugation verbs spell like "amāre"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, morphology, spelling, irregular-words

Why does *dō* conjugate differently from other first conjugation verbs in that you find a short *a* where otherwise you might expect a long *ā*?

**BACKGROUND**

Examples:

> amāre (dare), amārī (darī), amātūrus (datūrus), amāns (dans), amātus (datus), amābit (dabit), amābitur (dabitur), amātō (datō), amābat (dabat), amābātur (dabātur), amāret (daret), amārētur (darētur)

The only other irregularity of this sort I have found so far is *stō* having *statūrus* (not <strike>*stātūrus*</strike>).

At least according to [en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do#Latin) (where I got those forms), it seems *amō* sets the pattern for most first conjugation verbs.

I thought there might be an interesting story of derivation about *dō*.  Thanks.

Comment: And *status* (not *stātus*).

Comment: Closely related: [How do the verbs do and δίδωμι come from *deh₃-?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4132)

Comment: Actually, a few sources seem to say that the vowel is short in "status", but long in "stātūrus". See [brianpck's answer to "Is cultura a future participle?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1354/9) and [TKR's answer to "Stem for derivatives like figura, statura and cultura"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1366/9)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The story, as often, has to do with Proto-Indo-European laryngeals. Both these verbs had a laryngeal as the last consonant of the root: *deh₃-, *steh₂-. All the forms in Latin are based on the zero grade of these roots (i.e. the form without a vowel): *dh₃-, *sth₂-. Now, when a PIE laryngeal found itself between two consonants, in Latin the result was the vowel *a*: for example, *dh₃-tos > *datus*. So although these verbs are considered part of the first conjugation, in historical terms the *a* is not the first-conjugation vowel at all, but the reflex of a PIE laryngeal.

Comment: This raises the question how much these verbs were regularized to conform with the first conjugation as well as they do. Based on this background story, I could well believe there having been bigger differences than vowel length in early Latin or Proto-Italian.

Comment: I'm sure you're right - there has been a major re-adjustment of originally athematic verbs to conform the later Latin conjugational system. The short _a_ in _stare_ is ultimately traceable to a zero-grade *sth₂-. from a PIE stem *steh₂-, but the original athematic conjugation has been largely assimilated to the historical Latin conjugational system.