# Does the Latin nosco come from Greek?

Tags: classical-latin, etymology, greek, proto-indo-european, proto-italic

Does the Latin verb nosco come from Greek, or did the shared root (cf. γιγνώσκω) end up in Greek and Latin separately? [According to Wiktionary,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nosco#Latin) it seems to be the latter case, as the free dictionary traces the ancestry of nosco back to proto-Italic, not to Greek. This came as a surprise to me.

If indeed the two words evolved independently, then what would explain the shared stem vowel ō which comes from the PIE root *ǵneh₃-? Would the change have come from an ablaut early on and then ended up in the two languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latin *nōscō* and Greek *gignōskō* are cognates, but neither is directly derived from the other. They both come from the Proto-Indo-European root **ǵneh₃-* "to know", plus the inchoative **-sḱ-* marking the present tense.

To quote Wtrmute's answer [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4137/406):

> *h3 is called the "o-colouring laryngeal," which means that it "colours" (i.e., changes) a neighbouring e into *o or *ō: the former from *h3o and the latter from *oh3. See *h3ewis > ovis and *deh3[r/n]m̥ > dōnum.

**ǵneh₃-sḱ-* thus became **gnō-sk-*, which became Latin *gnōscō*, later *nōscō*.

Occasionally in PIE a present form would include reduplication, which usually indicated the perfect (much more common in Greek than Latin). That was the case here. From the reduplicated form **ǵi-ǵneh₃-sḱ-* came **gi-gnō-sk-*, and thus Greek *gignōskō*.

Comment: Just as an aside, reduplicated perfects were somewhat more common in old Latin; e.g., *fefeci* becomes Classical *feci.*

Comment: No word about *scire, ego scio*? Surely the comparison is not very doubtful? More challenging and out of *scope* for this question, would be comparison with *nactu*, ablative supine of *nanciscor*, from *h₂eh₂nóḱe "has reached, attained", perfective of *h₂neḱ- "to reach"

Comment: @vectory If _sciō_ and the inchoative _-sḱ-_ are related, it's farther back than PIE can be reconstructed with any certainty.